# How do I convert a date and time stored in a time object to a datetime object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using ODBC via a COM Dispatch object using ADODB.Recordset to read timestamp values from a PostgreSQL table in Python 2.7.  The fields contain full date and time value, such as "2019-07-03 12:34".  MyRecordset.Fields("time_column").Value is returning an object of type time, even though the time object contains all of the information from the field, including the date.

I need to compare the two times.  If the times were datetimes, there'd be no problem.  I could subtract the two and get a timedelta object.  The time class does not support subtraction because it's not designed to support dates.  So I need to convert my time objects to datetime objects.  I've found nothing on the internet talking about that particular conversion.  I thought I could use the time() method to convert my time objects to seconds since epoch, but I can't get that to work.  All the examples I've found of that work with the system time, not with a time object.

Assume StartTime and EndTime are time objects.

```
import time
StartTime_since_epoch = StartTime.time()
```

An exception is thrown whose only message is "time".  That happens when I try to refer to a property or method that doesn't exist.

I put in print statements to show me the types of my objects.  The result is:

```
FirstSegmentEndedTime is an object of type <type 'time'> with value of 07/03/19 12:05:29
FireTime is an object of type <type 'time'> with value of 07/03/19 12:01:29
```

What do I have to do to measure the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to convert your time objects to `struct_time` with `gmtime` and then build the datetimes from there:

```
import time
import datetime as dt

ti = time.time()

time.sleep(3)

tf = time.time()

ti_ts = time.gmtime(ti)
tf_ts = time.gmtime(tf)

# print(ti_ts) # check your struct_time structure if you need
# a different processing.

dti = dt.datetime(*tuple(ti_ts)[:6])
dtf = dt.datetime(*tuple(tf_ts)[:6])

print(repr(dtf - dti))
```

Output:

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3)
```